# How to generate pdf from php functions & variables in TCPDF

Tags: php

i have functions which takes stylesheet & gets output from other classes using OOP in PHP.
i need to generate the pdf using TCPDFm but i am facing problem how to pass in $html variable, i have read the manual for XHTML+ CSS using that does not explain the PHP variable output.
I am pating my code here, please help.

```
<?php
// define some HTML content with style
$html = <<<EOF
<?php $frame->HTML_DOCTYPE(); ?>

<html>
    <head><?php $frame->HTML_Title($page); $frame->HTML_CSS($page); $frame->HTML_JS($page); ?></head>
        <body>
            <div class='container_pngfix'>
                <?php echo $frame->Print_Top($page); ?>

                <div class='container_magazine'>
                    <div class='magazine_left'>
                        <?php 
                        /*if(FALSE == empty($_SESSION['wi_id']) && FALSE == empty($_SESSION['wi_type']) &&  0 == strcasecmp('bride',$_SESSION['wi_type'])){*/

                  if ($_REQUEST['magazineId']!="") {
                    echo $article->Print_Magazine_Issue($_REQUEST['magazineId']);
                  } else if ($_REQUEST['latestissue']) {
                    echo $article->Print_Magazine_Issue($article->getLatestMagazineId());
                  } else {
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['magazinedate'])) { $magazinedate=$_REQUEST['magazinedate']; } else { $magazinedate=""; }
                                if ($magazinedate=="") { $magazinedate=date("Y-m")."-01"; }

                    echo $article->Print_Magazine($magazinedate);
                  }
                        /*}else{
                            echo "<h2>Please Login/Register first to see Magazine details</h2>";
                        }*/
                ?>              
                </div>
                    <div class='magazine_right'><?php echo $frame->Print_RightSide_Articles($page); ?></div>
                    <div class='clearfloat'>&nbsp;</div>
                    <?php echo $frame->get_ContextualWeb($page,"low"); ?>
                </div>

            </div>
            <?php echo $frame->Print_Bottom_Links($page); ?>
            <?php $frame->Print_Bottom($page); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>EOF;

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_061.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

In this code i am calling multiple functions using objects of those classes.
All html & content of page is generating dynamically. i have problem of passing the PAGE html & PHP code in $html variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ob_start()](http://uk.php.net/ob_start) and [ob_get_clean()](http://uk.php.net/ob_get_clean) to get any output.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
?>
    <!-- HTML and PHP code here -->
<?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

`$html` will have your data that you can send to TCPDF

example for your situation:

```
<?php
    // your other script
    ob_start();
?>
<?php $frame->HTML_DOCTYPE(); ?>
<html>
    <head><?php $frame->HTML_Title($page); $frame->HTML_CSS($page); $frame->HTML_JS($page); ?></head>
    <body>
        <!-- rest of the page -->
    </body>
</html>
<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_061.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

Comment: can you write a little example using my case. that is using function that would be more helpful

Comment: i didnt get any error, but pdf page comes blank, for pdf to generate HTML & CSS should get pass under $html variable, i think here nothing gets passed.

Comment: then the `ob_get_clean()` works.. remove the line and look at your PDF processor, it gets the HTML ..

Comment: No, it does the same clean page without any output, if i am not wrong then can i ask, where we are passing html& php code to $html variable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16088/discussion-between-mihai-iorga-and-ankit)

Comment: here: `$html = ob_get_clean();`